# how to Implement Live Video Streaming in a Laravel PHP Web Application

Tags: laravel, video, streaming, live

The platform allows creators to run a live auction, a hybrid event, with bidders in the auction hall and online. Online bidders watch a live video and audio stream of the auction hall and bid via a web application. An auction event can be purely virtual with no auction hall.

The platform allows creators to run a live auction, a hybrid event, with bidders in the auction hall and online. Online bidders watch a live video and audio stream of the auction hall and bid via a web application. An auction event can be purely virtual with no auction halls.

Comment: I think, best choose - use some vide platform for video stream. If u try to make it - u get a lot of pain.